# X-Com 1: Having a secondary weapon

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

I play UFO Defense / Enemy Unknown (X-Com) since its out now. And I always equip a weapon on the right hand slot and a grenade in the left hand slot.

On most Longplay videos, people equip grenades on the belt and take them from there when needed (which costs Timeunits)

Why is this? Is it influencing the aiming or timeunit use of my soldiers to have a weapon in one hand and a grenade in the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the UFOpaedia, having an item in your off hand when firing a two-handed weapon reduces your accuracy by 20%:

http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Accuracy_formula

Comment: thx a lot for the ufopedia link and your answer.

Comment: Tip: you can carry a grenade in your off-hand and *drop it* before firing. Dropping from the hand only costs 2 time units as opposed to 8 or more to stow it. Just make sure it isn't armed...

Comment: So which weapons count as one-handed?

Comment: @KerrekSB all 3 pistols (both in UFO1 & 2) & all thrown items (grenades, explosives etc.) are 1-handed (e.g. in early game you can couple a laser pistol & frag grenade without any accuracy penalty) - everything else is 2-handed. Both original & OpenXcom data files confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because grenades in X-COM are incredibly effective, some play with them as their *main* weapon with a rifle (of some sort) being the backup weapon.

Comment: Except when you use explosives you're very prone to blowing up the loot.